# Difference between the two expression in java

Tags: java, expression

I am not able to understand that what is the difference between these two operations :-

1. abc == null
2. null == abc

Both of these expressions result in same output. I have searched many places but was not able to find any reference with the same.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

They are both the same. In some languages like C and C++ the second form is used to avoid accidentally using the `=` instead of the `==` operator.

The form:

```
null = abc
```

will cause a compiler error, whereas the `abc = null` will compile and leave you at your own chasing a difficult to find bug.

In modern languages however, like Java and C#, this has no meaning as the first form will still be caught as an error, if used as a boolean statement.

Comment: but notice that this isn't as big an issue in Java as it is in other languages. If you use the variable-first expression with `=` rather than `==` in a boolean context you will get a compiler error. e.g. `if (abc = null)` results in `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to boolean`

Comment: @Adel Boutros: Because the compiler will throw an error and you will immediately see it. In an IDE it will be red highlighted. With the first form, you will only find it out in runtime.

Comment: not really, becuase using a `abc = null` is not a valid expression for an `if` statement and you will still get an error!

Answer (score 1):

Often, using the `null == abc` (constant first, then variable) is recommended, as a mistaken `null = abc` will give you an error, as opposed to the accidental assignment `abc = null` that will not get caught by a compiler.

Comment: abc=null is still caught as an incompatible type error when used in if statements or boolean assignments.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no difference at all between them.